# How does default Debian boot drive encryption works?

Tags: encryption, linux, luks, debian

When installing Debian, I chose an option to create Encrypted LVM (Logical Volume Management). So now, when I turn on my PC, it asks me for an encryption password.

It looks ok, but how does it work? What does GRUB initialize to ask my password, if the full drive with my OS and Kernel is encrypted?

How does it decrypt my files after I put in my password? If there are any possible problems with this system?

Comment: Are you sure `/boot` is encrypted? Last I checked the debian installer left `/boot` unencrypted when doing its Encrypted LVM install (it's been a while since I've checked though, I always do a custom install). The [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_.28GRUB.29) may be helpful.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald not really sure, will check this

Comment: @biryulin04 It is unencrypted. However, you can utilize GRUB2 to encrypt your boot partition as well, but this is not done by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Debian boot sequence

1. Grub is not encrypted. Grub is located on `/boot` wich hold `kernel` and `initramfs`, **readable** without encryption.
2. Grub *load* `kernel`, `kernel` load `initramfs`. `initramfs` hold a full filesystem,
   not encrypted, with common directories `/bin, /etc, /lib, /lib/module ...` containing everything nedeed for encryption and filesystems.
3. Once `initramfs` loaded, the kernel run a script (called `init`) automatically at startup.
4. `start` script hold all procedure to

   - load required modules,
   - ask user for password,
   - check filesystem if needed and
   - mount final root `/`.
5. Then once done, run `pivot_root` in order to become able to `umount /initramfs` before continuing normal boot on finalized `/`.

Answer (score 0):

The `/boot` partition is not encrypted for exactly the reason you mention in your question. Typically, files and data should not be written to that partition for exactly this reason.